# Filter entries in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter

I have an array with the following entries:

```
abc / def
abc.def
! abc def
abc def ?
```

How can I remove non-alpha characters, that are not attached to a word?

So in my case only the following entries would remain:

```
abc def
abc.def
abc def
abc def
```

I tried with the following code, but it didn't help:

```
arr = arr.filter(function(v) {
    return v.match(/[a-zA-Z]*/)
});
```

Comment: According to your exit example it seems you want to full trim spaces also, right?

Comment: Please define special characters? non-alpha?

Comment: @Saleem: Yes, non-alpha.

Comment: good. Please see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are all strings, you want to use map

```
array.map(function(string) {
    return string.replace(/\W\s+/g, '');
});
```

Use the non-word character regex `\W` to quickly remove any special characters.

Comment: Just realized that and fixed it

Comment: what about spaces? will it not replace them too

Comment: That is incorrect. My regex checks for a non-word-character followed by a space. Spaces themselves will stay put

Comment: "Spaces themselves will stay put" --- `'a  b'.replace(/\W\s+/g, ''); // "ab"`

Comment: "!abc / def! * &".replace(/\W\s+/g, "") outputs "!abc def&"

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
result = subject.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s](?=\s|$)/img, "");
```

where `subject` holds actual text to filter.

see demo https://regex101.com/r/mW2pJ7/1

> **INPUT**

```
abc / def`
abc.def`
! abc def`
abc def ?`
```

> **OUTPUT**

- abc  def
- abc.def
- abc def
- abc def